# Google Apps Marketpalce Migration

Tags: google-app-engine, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, google-apps, google-apps-marketplace

I have integrated my application with Google apps marketplace with old version of OpenID and getting the data from Google calendar by using Google calendar version 2 API. Now I need to integrate every thing to new version. I have confused a little bit as Google is providing various authentication and authorization process. I looked in to OpenID connect, JWT (JSON Web Token), Google calendar version 3 service account. May any one please help me out from this issue like that should I use to authenticate as well as for authorization. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2 gives a good overview on various ways to authenticate with Google APIs and when to use them. For instance JWT is useful when your application uses Google APIs to store/retrieve its own data i.e. not to access data of your application's user.

Also see https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May I know which process do we need to follow for Authroization
1) Is service account. 2) OAuth 2.0 by using access token & refresh token. I am confused in these two because in google calendar version 2 we don't have the process of access token and refresh token. So Do we have this process in in GApps.

Comment: You most likely want to use (2), assuming your app needs to access user's calendar events. Service account is primarily used for app specific data i.e. for instance your app wanted to store some internal data (not data that belongs to user of your app) and you choose to store it on Google Drive then you will use service account to access Google Drive.

Comment: Thanks Gagan. My main motive for using Service account to apply Single Sign on from Google directly to my application without any username and password. If this problem is resolved my using OAUth 2.0 then it would be good because it is really messes using OpenID authentication. This relay make me feel good thanks.

Comment: I have implemented the code for Goolge apps login using OAuth 2.0, but the issue is that when the user is trying to login then it always generates new access token, refresh token and ID token, one more think here what is the use of ID Token if we have access token & refresh token,